# Unreal Engine 5 Websockets Plugin Issue to A Secure Python Server

Tags: python, websocket, unreal-engine5

So I am trying to connect to my Python Secure Websocket server from Unreal Engine 5.3 using the BlueprintsWebsocket Plugin and I seem to be getting the following error:

> LogWebSockets: Warning: Lws(Error): SSL error: unable to get local
> issuer certificate (preverify_ok=0;err=20;depth=0)

I have looked at multiple troubleshooting guides and it says to take the cacert.pem file from the Certificate folder in the Engine folder and add it to a Certificate folder in my project. I still get the same issue. I can connect to the Python server from my Webserver and I am using wss as the protocol. My server has a Cert from Let's Encrypt. If any additional information is needed I will try to provide.

If anyone has been through this issue and can advise me, that would be great. Thanks.